# How to insert and retrive "html code" in database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

Can anyone tell me how do I properly take special characters as input from a textbox, and insert it into database and retrieve it and display it on another textbox. For example, how do I deal with content like this, `<html><body><anything>" " '` its has html tag, special chars and also some random text which looks like html tag, but is not. Or is there any way to deal with it in codeigniter?

My code example are.

```
<input type="text" id="videoTitle" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($videoToEdit['title']); ?>>
```

to take input from user. It is also echoing the same content in the input field.

```
$data['title'] = htmlentities($this->input->post('title'));
```

to store the user input.

```
<strong><?php echo html_entity_decode($video['title']); ?></strong>
```

to display the content in some `div`. And doing this, the value stored in the database is
`&amp;lt;body&amp;gt; &lt;Some&gt; title &lt;l&gt;&quot;m&quot;`
and the output I get is
`<body> title "m"`. The solution I'm looking for is similar to what stackoverflow does. Like, we can input whatever character we need and it is displayed exactly as it is in the comments below.

Comment: Why would you like to store this information to begin with?

Comment: @Chax Can't understand. There are many use cases. Consider user sending HTML input to be stored in DB.

Comment: You can (and should) encode the HTML before saving. (< becomes lt;) etc.

Comment: @chax I don't think there should be a question like "why would you wanna do it?" in programming field or in fact, in any field. Please provide answer if you can, otherwise, don't question my question.

Comment: @ole I tried `urlencode()`, tried `htmlspecialchars()`, tried `htmlentities()` for encoding the data before inserting to database and `urldecode()`, `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: Just wanted to know if this could be optimised instead of providing a generic solution. Perhaps my question should have been: "Do you want to store the information inside the html or do you want to save the html itself". And i think the question "why do you want to do it" is relevant in any field.

Comment: I want to store the exact html code or anything that looks like an html code. Just like this stack overflow does, where you can add any character in the comment input field and is display exactly as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for encoding and saving it to DB:

```
htmlentities($textareaContents);      // ==> Send to DB
```

And while retrieving, you can make use of [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
echo html_entity_decode($textFromDB); // ==> Display on HTML
```

In short, the above functions do these:

```
htmlentities("<html>");             // ==> "&lt;html&gt;"
html_entity_decode("&lt;html&gt;"); // ==> "<html>"
```

Comment: I still get error. I tried inserting `<body> <some> text` but when I display it, I get output like this `<body> text`. Though the `<some>` is stored in the database.

Comment: @RobinLama Can you show your full code in the question, please?

Comment: @RobinLama Okay, try doing this way: `html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($dbtext));`.

Comment: I still don't get the output.

Comment: @RobinLama Can you show us the full PHP code? With what's the output it shows in the browser?

Comment: updated the question again. That's all the code I can put here.

Comment: @RobinLama I was just interested in the contents of the PHP file. And also the HTML file. Can you do that simple thing?